# List of odbc drivers viewing R

Tags: r, ms-access, odbc, rodbc

I am running into the following problem while trying to use `odbcConnectExcel2007`

```
library(RODBC)
wb <- "some_file.xlsb"
con2 <- odbcConnectExcel2007(wb)
```

returns:

```
[RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specifiedODBC connection failed
```

In Windows data sources (GUI part) I see:
[image: ODBC Admin 64 bit]

So my thinking is that MS Access Database 32 bit driver should be enough. (My office and R are running in 32 bit mode right now.).

But when I execute:

```
odbcDataSources()
```

I get:

```
                       CompanySQL                      AWS_REDDDB 
"ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"         "Amazon Redshift (x64)"
```

So my question is why I do not see MS Access driver in `odbcDataSources()` results

Comment: I think you need to run r32 bits sorry

Comment: @Bruno, I am running 32 bit R, I switched to it in `Tools -> Global Options` in RStudio

Comment: I get `odbcDataSources()#
                                             dBASE Files                                              Excel Files                                       MS Access Database 
   "Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)" "Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)"               "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)"`

Comment: Does `list.files()` show the "some_file.xlsb" file? Is it in your current working directory? Also a "xlsb" is an MS Excel file, so it's not clear to me why you are worried about the MS Access database driver.

Comment: @MrFlick, `list.files()` shows `some_file.xlsb`. It it is not in my current directory, but I provide proper path `list.files("proper_path")` shows the file. I already tried `readxlsb` and `excel.link` and they did not work

Comment: So it shows up both when you run `list.files()` and when you run `list.files("proper_path")`? The error just sounds like you are not passing the correct path to the file. If it's in a subdirectory relative to your current working directory (`getwd()`) but that in the path. `wb <- "proper_path/some_file.xlsb"`

Comment: @MrFlick Sorry for confusion, I meant that is shows up only when I run `list.files("proper_path")`

Comment: So did you try with `wb <- "proper_path/some_file.xlsb"`? Do you get the exact same error? Does `file.exists(wb)` return TRUE?

Comment: @MrFlick, Yes, I tried it with the same error. Yes `file.exists(wb)` returns true.